# IE reserves space for scrollbar in frame

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a frame-set and each frame has a table with `width:100%`. In IE 8 and 9, the table does not fill the whole window, but instead has a strange right margin. In all other browsers it worked fine.

[image: space reserved for scrollbar]

I confirmed that it is not related to margin/padding and is to do with scrollbar because if I change the scrollbar width in the control panel, the reserved space changes too. If the page is viewed outside of frame this problem will not happen.

This is lagacy code. Each frame has `scrolling=auto`. From the internet I saw two related discussions:

- [vertical scrollbar problem in IE](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/96354-vertical-scrollbar-problem-ie)
- [Reserved space for vertical scrollbar in IE](http://www.heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2006/spacescrollbarie/)

However I still can't find a solution. Adding `scroll=no` to the body of the page will eliminate the space, but this prevents scrollbar from showing when needed. I tried a few other solution but can't find a fully working one yet.

EDIT: This only happens in vertical split frame.

**Sample Code:**

index.html

```
<html>
<frameset rows="150,*" cols="*"  framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="no">
<frame scrolling="auto" noresize src="top.html" name="menu">
<frame scrolling="auto" noresize src="bottom.html" name="main">
</frameset>
</html>
```

top.html

```
<html>
<body marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 bgColor="#AAFFAA">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" border=1>
<tr>
<td width="100%" align=middle>TOP<td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

bottom.html

```
<html>
<body marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 bgColor="#FFAAAA">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" border=1>
<tr>
<td width="100%" align=middle>bottom<td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting your code/site will help in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i cant comment under the question.

Did you try to replace the scrolling with an oveflow?

try adding a style `overflow: auto:` or `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: yes it works. Would you mind adding my findings to your answer?

At the end I found out that by having `style="overflow:auto"` on the body element of sub pages will resolve the issue.

The `<frame scrolling="auto" ` has no effect.

Note that if the page is in zoom mode this will sometimes create horizontal scrollbar, which may confuse you if you are trying this solution.